# Im trying to get an existing user and a users Id using MongoDB and JWT

Tags: node.js, mongodb, jwt

In my app i want to display a page with the users profile information but in my backend im trying to create the routes. Heres what i have so far.

```
  const getExistingUser = async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const user = await User.findById(req.params.id).select("-password")
      if (!user) return res.status(400).send({error: 'User not found'});
      res.json(user)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
      res.status(500).send({ error: "server error"})
    }
```

}

```
const findUserById = async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const user = await User.findById(req.query.id).select("-password")
      if(!user) return res.status(400).send({error: 'User not found'});
      res.json(user)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
      res.status(500).send({ error: "server error"}) 
    }
  }
```

Heres my schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true},
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    password: { type: String, required: true},
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now}
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema)
```

Comment: Please let me know if more code needs to displayed.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The error that appears is the error block that i set up in the code to detect whether the user is found

Comment: What does `console.log(user)` print to the console?

Comment: When console logging the user i get "null"

Comment: Ok, so work backwards from there.  First simplify your query (remove `select`), if that's no good, keep working backwards to `req.params` etc.  If removing select works, then your select syntax is wrong.